# Noise when I plug in my speakers trough usb hub

Tags: usb, audio, speakers, noise, usb-hub

My speakers make background noise when I connect the power usb cable to my pc through a usb 2.0 hub.

When I connect it to usb 3.0 pc port, noise stops.

Do you think the quality of the hub, or being 2.0 could produce noise.

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely poor shielding and/or grounding in the USB hub.  The speed of the USB hub will have no effect on the quality of the sound.  Speaker noise is often attributed to poor shielding and grounding.